# Laravel 5.3 search MethodNotAllowedHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 218:

Tags: laravel, search

I am working on laravel 5.3 search function that is supposed to search for service_provided in table called services

below is my form

```
    @extends('layouts.app')
@section('title', '| View Search Results')
@section('content')
<div class="container">
<div class="flex-center position-ref full-height">


            <div class="content">
                <div class="title m-b-md">
                    Service 
                </div>
                {!! Form::open(['route' => 'search.create']) !!}
                <div class="container" id="SearchBox">
                <div class="col-xs-8 col-xs-offset-2">

                 <div class="input-group">

                {!! Form::text('search',null,array('class' => 'form-control','placeholder' => 'Search term...','aria-describedby' => 'basic-addon2')) !!}
                  <span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon2">
                  {!! Form::submit('Search',array('class'=> 'btn btn-default')) !!}
                  </span>
                </div>

                </div>
                </div>
                {!! Form::close() !!}

            </div>
        </div>
</div>

@endsection
```

My Seach function create is as below

```
  public function create(Request $request)
    {
        //// Gets the query string from our form submission 
    $query = $request->input('search');
    // Returns an array of articles that have the query string located somewhere within 
    // our articles titles. Paginates them so we can break up lots of search results.
    $services = DB::table('services')->where('city', 'LIKE', '%' . $query . '%')->paginate(10);

    // returns a view and passes the view the list of articles and the original query.
    return view('search.search', compact('services', 'query'));
    }
```

my route is as follows

```
Route::get('search.index',array('as'=>'index','uses'=>'SearchController@index'));
Route::get('search.create',array('as'=> 'create','SearchController@create'));
```

The error message im getting when i submit the form is as below

Whoops, looks like something went wrong.
1/1 MethodNotAllowedHttpException in /home/archie/servicepap/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/RouteCollection.php line 218:

```
in RouteCollection.php line 218
at RouteCollection->methodNotAllowed(array('GET', 'HEAD', 'PUT', 'PATCH', 'DELETE')) in RouteCollection.php line 205
at RouteCollection->getRouteForMethods(object(Request), array('GET', 'HEAD', 'PUT', 'PATCH', 'DELETE')) in RouteCollection.php line 158
at RouteCollection->match(object(Request)) in Router.php line 780
at Router->findRoute(object(Request)) in Router.php line 610
at Router->dispatchToRoute(object(Request)) in Router.php line 596
at Router->dispatch(object(Request)) in Kernel.php line 267
at Kernel->Illuminate\Foundation\Http\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 53
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in CheckForMaintenanceMode.php line 46
at CheckForMaintenanceMode->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 137
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 33
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 104
at Pipeline->then(object(Closure)) in Kernel.php line 149
at Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter(object(Request)) in Kernel.php line 116
at Kernel->handle(object(Request)) in index.php line 53
at require_once('/home/archie/servicepap/public/index.php') in server.php line 21
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hi i also had that challenge but my problem was that i was trying to launch my application on a diffrent plat form so i had to change my Routes as below

Your code :::

```
Route::get('search.index',array('as'=>'index','uses'=>'SearchController@index'));
Route::get('search.create',array('as'=> 'create','SearchController@create'));
```

Change it to :::

```
Route::any('search.index',array('as'=>'index','uses'=>'SearchController@index'));
Route::any('search.create',array('as'=> 'create','SearchController@create'));
```

but this is not the best way.. you can use match and specify an array of your http verbs

Answer (score 1):

Form sends `post` request by default, so use this route:

```
Route::post('search/create', array('as'=> 'search.create', 'SearchController@create'));
```

Comment: Try to set method expicitly `{!! Form::open(['method' => 'Post', 'route' => 'search.create']) !!}`

Comment: @ArchieRombo, copy and paste route from my answer, you're also using wrong route names.